# Apache HttpClient resolving domain to IP address and not matching certificate

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

When using the Apache HttpComponents HttpClient library (4.0.2) I'm having a problem where the certificate doesn't get validated properly. The certificate is valid for the domain name (let's call it example.com) however it's getting validated against the IP address instead:

> hostname in certificate didn't match: <123.123.123.123> !=
>   <*.example.com>

My code for making the connection is:

```
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);            
    String url = "https://www.example.com";
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
    String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()).trim();
```

The certificate itself shows as valid when connecting through a web browser and is valid for the domain name I'm connecting to:

> CN = *.example.com

The certificate is also added to the Java keystore (tested using regular `HttpsURLConnection`).

Any ideas why this code uses the IP address instead of the domain name?

Comment: So the domain cannot be resolved to the IP when it comes to SSL. So you can't use an IP certificate to secure a domain. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a known bug with HttpClient 4.0.2 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-996
The bug suggests any of the following:

- Upgrade to version 4.0.3 or newer
- Downgrade to 4.0.1
- Use the AllowAllHostnameVerifier