# SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <50.19.233.255> != <*.heroku.com>

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to call heroku's developer api from java, but I get the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <50.19.233.255> != <*.heroku.com>
```

My code looks like this:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.heroku.com/apps");
    String token = "d6d7ea6e-6e71-4f13-b0ff-ed9ee9d56c37";
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

If I try it with *curl* it works fine:

```
    curl "https://api.heroku.com/apps" -H"Authorization: Bearer d6d7ea6e-6e71-4f13-b0ff-ed9ee9d56c37"
```

Why does the java code act differently to curl?

P.S. I'm aware that others have asked this questions, but all the answers, e.g:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266768

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904473

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356821

suggest that I should override the certificate hostname check, which surely defeats the point (and certainly isn't production-ready)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is described in [Apache HttpClient resolving domain to IP address and not matching certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909224/apache-httpclient-resolving-domain-to-ip-address-and-not-matching-certificate).
It appears to be a bug in the version of HTTPClient you are using, where it compares the target IP instead of the target hostname with the subject certificate. Please use a fixed version of HTTPClient instead.